# How can pre-load the value in Angular material select?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-select2, angularjs-material

I want to pre-load the value in md-select

I have the following code

```
<md-select ng-model="country" ng-model-options="{trackBy: '$value.code'}" >
    <md-optgroup label="Country">
        <md-option ng-value="country" ng-repeat="country in countries">
                    {{country.name}}
        </md-option>
    </md-optgroup>
</md-select>
```

**Controller**

```
 $scope.country = "usa"; //I will receive only the key from the server side 
                         //in the response object

$scope.countries = [{"code":"usa","name":"United States of America"},
  {"code":"ind","name":"India"},
  {"code":"eng","name":"England"},    
  {"code":"aus","name":"Australia"}];
```

Here I want to load "United States of America" initially.

This is currently not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume your service returns the key `"usa"`, it checks for the existence of key in the drop down array and assign the object to the `$scope.country`,

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.service = "usa";
$scope.countries = [{"code":"usa","name":"United States of America"},
  {"code":"ind","name":"India"},
  {"code":"eng","name":"England"},    
  {"code":"aus","name":"Australia"}];

   angular.forEach($scope.countries, function(value) {
        if (value.code === $scope.service ) {
            $scope.country ={code: $scope.service , name: value.name};
            console.log($scope.country);
        }
    });

});
```

[`WORKING DEMO`](https://plnkr.co/edit/geUc7AwJbZwCkFHqdI1X?p=preview)

Comment: I want to send only the code from selected object. ng-value="country.code" not pre-load the data. Also selection not works. If I select any one countries, it select the last entry in the dropdown. How can I send only the key